# By Which method I can solve $y'(\frac{x}{2})+y'(\frac{x}{3})+y(x)=0$ numerically?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods

I know some method to solve the normal type of ordinary differential equations but I don"t know how to treat with this form
$$y'(\frac{x}{2})+y'(\frac{x}{3})+y(x)=0$$
with initial value $y(0)=1$

thanks for your helping

Comment: Why equation in title don't match that of body?

Comment: With **CAS** and using **MellinTransfrom** I have general solution,but CAS can't find `inversMellinTransfrom`: $$y(x)=\mathcal{M}_s^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{5} 2^{\frac{1}{2} s (1+s)} c_1 \Gamma (s)
   \left(-\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2}\right)_s\right](x)$$ where:$\left(-\frac{3}{2};\frac{3}{2}\right)_s$ is  q-Pochhammer symbol.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk Can you give me the value of $y(0.1)$

Comment: For: `-1<x<1` solution by sum https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/143240/solution-to-differential-difference-equation?rq=1  : $$y(x)=\sum _{i=0}^{\infty } \frac{(-1)^{2+i} 2^{\frac{1}{2} (-1+i) i} x^i}{i! \left(-1;\frac{2}{3}\right)_i}$$,where: $\left(-1;\frac{2}{3}\right)_i$ is  q-Pochhammer symbol,for: $y\left(\frac{1}{10}\right)\approx 0.95276$

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk thank you so so much and if you can give me the value of $y(0.05)$ and $y(0.2)$....sorry If I tired you

Comment: For: $y\left(\frac{1}{20}\right)\approx 0.975718$ and $y\left(\frac{1}{5}\right)\approx 0.910447$.